# Cant select files and move to another directory

Tags: python-3.x

**Cant move png and jpg files from src to dst. Example of file dir: dst/face_image/Aaron_Eckhart**

```
import os, sys
import shutil
src = '/home/mihuzz/PycharmProjects/dc/face_image'
dst = '/home/mihuzz/PycharmProjects/dc/face'

folder = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(('png','jpg')):
            shutil.move(src, dst)
            #folder.append(files)
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: no error. it just copy everything. need copy only files

Answer (score 0):

You are not appending the filename to the `shutil.move` command, you are moving the whole directory to the other path.

```
import os, sys
import shutil
src = '/home/mihuzz/PycharmProjects/dc/face_image'
dst = '/home/mihuzz/PycharmProjects/dc/face'

folder = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(('png','jpg')):
            shutil.move(os.path.join(src, file), dst)
            #folder.append(files)
```

Comment: If it helped you, please upvote and select the answer as correct. Thanks